# Python3 Magic for a Django project

Tags: python, django, python-magic

I need the python-magic package for a Django project. However, I found out that since I am using python3, I need the python3-magic package, which I can either get using pip3 or using apt-get.
I am a macOS user, so I don't have an apt-get, and I cannot install the package using pip3. It gives me the following error when I type: `pip3 install python3-magic`.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-magic (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-magic
```

Is there any way I can get this package for my Django project? No matter what I do, the package appears uninstalled on my VS Code.

Comment: I think the equivalent of `apt-get` on mac is `brew`?

Comment: For `pip3` it is `python-magic`: https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install this through `pip3`, the name of the package is [**`python-magic`** <sup>[PyPi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/), not <s>`python3-magic`</s>, so:

```
pip3 install python-magic
```

If you use `apt-get`, you can work with `python3-magic` and `python-magic`. These are *not* links to a Python package, but in essence intallations scripts that will work with `pip3` and `pip` respectively. See for example the [files of the `python3-magic` package <sup>[ubuntu-packages]</sup>](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/python3-magic/filelist).

Comment: I have tried python-magic with pip3 too. The problem is that the package doesn't appear installed when I try and use it in my project

Comment: @Panda: are you sure your project is not using a virtual environment, or another interpreter than the one where you install this package for?

Comment: I think so. There is a folder called A, where I have activated the environment, and inside it is my django folder

Comment: @Panda: you should activate the environment in the shell where you call `pip3`.